# Textbox change event not effecting immediately jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enable img button in while typing in textbox. But it is working after lost focusing from textbox. How can see changes immediately?

```
      $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").change(function () {
            if (myPlugin.metReq() == true && $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").val().length > 0) //return true or false
                $("#imgSubmit").removeAttr("disabled").css('opacity', 1);
            else
                $("#imgSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity', 0.5);
        });
```

Comment: How about using .keydown() function?

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the <del>`keyup`</del> `input` event.

```
$("[id$='txtNewPass2']").on('input', function () {
        if (myPlugin.metReq() == true && $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").val().length > 0) //return true or false
            $("#imgSubmit").removeAttr("disabled").css('opacity', 1);
        else
            $("#imgSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity', 0.5);
    });
```

<del>The reason for recommending a `keyup` as opposed to a `keydown` is that in the below snippet, if you use a `keydown` the event will always be one letter behind.</del>

**Update:**

After playing around with the example I created below. I can see that the `input` event creates a much smoother update effect. See the example below to see how all three work comparitively

**Sample:**

```js
$('#keyup-input').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#keyup-div').html($('#keyup-input').val());
  });
$('#keydown-input').on('keydown', function () {
    $('#keydown-div').html($('#keydown-input').val());
  });
$('#input-input').on('input', function () {
    $('#input-div').html($('#input-input').val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Keyup:</h1>
<input id="keyup-input" type="text" />
<div id="keyup-div"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1>Keydown:</h1>
<input id="keydown-input" type="text" />
<div id="keydown-div"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1>Input:</h1>
<input id="input-input" type="text" />
<div id="input-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@James123 I hope it will work as you want.I just used `Input` event instead of  `change`

```
$("[id$='txtNewPass2']").on("input",function () {
            if (myPlugin.metReq() == true && $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").val().length > 0) //return true or false
                $("#imgSubmit").removeAttr("disabled").css('opacity', 1);
            else
                $("#imgSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity', 0.5);
        });
```